# Restrict SharePoint Store app to a single site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using the most recent SharePoint Online. I want to add an app from the SharePoint Store to only one site collection, but restrict other site owners from adding it to their site collections.

I know it's possible to restrict a *custom* SharePoint App to only one [site collection app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog), however, when adding an app from the SharePoint Store, it gives access to all site collections in the tenant, which I don't want.

When I go to the admin dashboard > More Features > Apps > Manage Licenses, it says: "This app has been purchased for everyone in your organization. Everyone can use this app.", but there doesn't seem to be a way to change it.

Is there a way to restrict this access, such that when a site owner from another site collection goes to their "Site contents > Your Apps" they **do not** see the app under "Apps you can add"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is by design that we cannot restrict SharePoint store app to a single site collection.

Comment: I see -- thank you!